# How to pre-select an option of a dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that is dynamically created.

here is the script for that.

```
function getreferData(dataArray)

{               
  var ray = dataArray.splice(0,1)
  let table = document.getElementById('thead1');
  var tableHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
  table.appendChild(tableHeaderRow);

  for(i=0;i<ray[0].length;i++){
    var tableHeader = document.createElement("th");
    tableHeaderRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
    tableHeader.innerHTML = ray[0][i];
  }
  let tbody = document.getElementById('perf');

  for (var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)
  {
    let row = document.createElement("tr")

    for (var j=0;j<dataArray[i].length;j++)
    {
      if (j==6){
        let col = document.createElement("td")
        col.appendChild(createDropdown("status-"+dataArray[i][4],dataArray[i][6])); //here i have passed the values
        var lbl = document.createElement("label");
        lbl.setAttribute("for","status");
        col.appendChild(lbl);
        row.appendChild(col)
      }

      else {
        let col = document.createElement("td")
        col.innerText = dataArray[i][j]
        row.appendChild(col) }                 
    }
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
}

function createDropdown(id,se) {
  let selectArray = ["Select option","Acknowledged","Interview sched", "Hired", "Rejected", "On Hold"];
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.setAttribute("id", id);
  select.setAttribute("class","browser-default")
  selectArray.forEach(function (r) {
  select.options.add( new Option(r, r)); //if r = se then options[r].selected = true;
   });
  fragment.appendChild(select);
  return fragment;
}
```

Now I want to pre-select the value passed in `se --> function createDropdown(id,se)`
something like if `options[r].selected = true;`

I tried solution provided online but it did not work.

Please let me know if you need some more details.

Comment: Adding from a little bit HTML for testing could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the [`Option()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) documentation I concluded that the best solution is to simply pass a boolean flag to third and fourth argument of the `Option` constructor. For example

```
let selected = r === se;
select.options.add( new Option(r, r, selected, selected));
```

I am leaving my original answer below since it technically still a valid solution.

#### Original Answer

The solution is quite trivial. instead of adding the new `Option` instance directly into the `select.options` collection, assign it to a variable and edit any property you need. In this case you want to update the `selected` property based on the condition you already know.

For example, replace this line

```js
select.options.add( new Option(r, r));
```

with

```js
let option = new Option(r, r);
option.selected = r === se;
select.options.add(option);
```

Answer (score 1):

It works by storing a reference to the created option and setting it's selected attribute based upon whether it matches with passed "se".

Following is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/r8h2d31w/5/

```js
function createDropdown(id, se) {
  let selectArray = ["Select option", "Acknowledged", "Interview sched", "Hired", "Rejected", "On Hold"];
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.setAttribute("id", id);
  select.setAttribute("class", "browser-default")
  selectArray.forEach(function(r) {
    let opt = new Option(r, r);
    if (r === se) {
      opt.setAttribute("selected", true);
    }
    select.options.add(opt); //if r = se then options[r].selected = true;
  });
  fragment.appendChild(select);
  return fragment;
}
```